# Adding same marker again after remove() - Android

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

After I remove a marker from Google Map, using marker.remove(), I want to add the same marker again. Like, I want to Hide and Show the marker.

I don't want to create MarkerOptions every time. Is there a simple way? though there should have been an intuitive way to do this simple thing.

Comment: This sounds like a conceptual issue? Creating `MarkerOptions` is simple, so either update DataModels which are related to your marker, re-use instance of map marker (without deleting the marker)

Comment: @longilong no!  it is ridiculous to to keep 2 objects, one to Add and other to Remove the marker from the map. Either its answer is "There is no direct/right way to do it" OR "user marker.isVisible = true/false"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found is:

If you just want to hide and show, the use this

```
marker.isVisible = true/false     Or    marker.setVisibility(true/false)  //for java
```

There is no direct way to add a Removed marker again, unless u keep reference to MarkerOptions. You can save its reference like `marker.tag = markerOptions`. Although,  in the function description of `remove()` it says it doesnt guarantee any operation on marker after `remove()` is called. But i think TAG wont go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you expect to get as a result but if you just want to reuse marker with same values, you can create a var of MarkerOptions and store MarkerOptions options in it and reuse it.

creating the marker var:

```
       MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
```

reuse it(mMap is your googleMap var):

```
mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

Comment: i didnt like this solution. cz for this i need to maintain 2 lists (or list of pairs) Marker and MarkerOptions. One to REMOVE and other to ADD marker. This is weird.

Comment: So you should rephrase your question with some relevant code and explain your wanted result better. I offered a solution for the question you asked above :)

Comment: @M.UsmanKhan U should go for a model class which holds marker and marker options instead of list or pairs

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways and with both ways, you only need to maintain one object against a marker. The main difference between these two approaches is that you need to make marker object mutable if you want to use the add and remove marker.

1. **Using Visibility**

   `marker?.isVisible = true/false`
2. **Using Adding and removing**:

   `var marker = mMap?.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(Location))
   marker?.remove()
   // To add again
   marker = mMap?.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(marker!!.position))`

---

**Edit 1**: After reading your comment, the second approach needs to be modified

According to docs: tag property can be used to store any data and it's never read/written by the map, so it can be used to store ID of your data model

use the following data class

```
data class MarkerData(val id: String, val title: String, var icon: BitmapDescriptor?, val position: LatLng)
```

You can add/remove variables as you desired.

copy the following function in your class

```
private fun getMarkerOption(model: MarkerData? = null,marker: Marker? = null): Pair<String,MarkerOptions>{
        check(!(model == null && marker == null)) { "Both options can't be null" }
        var m = model ?: array.first { it.id == marker!!.id }
        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(m.position).icon(m.icon).title(m.title)
        return Pair(m.id,markerOptions)
    }
```

Customize the third line `val markerOptions` according to your requirement

Note that array refers to your list where you will store all the data for markers.

How to use (with model):

```
var options = getMarkerOption(array.first())
var marker = mMap?.addMarker(options.second)
marker?.tag = options.first
```

How to use(with marker):

```
options = getMarkerOption(marker = marker)
marker = mMap?.addMarker(options.second)
marker?.tag = options.first
```

Comment: u r considering only "position" of marker. It can have custom icon, text, view, tag, etc.  Also, in the function description of remove() it says it doesnt guarantee any operation on marker after remove() is called.